# Verify that the family of functions is a solution to differential $\frac{dP}{dt}=P(1-P)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm struggling with simplifying the derivative of the function.

Here is the function and derivative:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=P(1-P)\\P=\frac{c_1e^t}{1+c_1e^t}$$

I have to get the function to "look" like the derivative right? Ignore the arrow in my work.    Thanks for taking a look at my problem.
[image]

Comment: Your final result is incorrect. In the last line, when you factored out $c_{1}e^{t}/(1+c_{1}e^{t})$ from the previous line, you should still have a $1+c_{1}e^{t}$ term in the numerator, not a $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

$$P = \dfrac{c_1 e^t}{1 + c_1 e^t} \implies \dfrac{dP}{dt} = \dfrac{c_1 e^t}{c_1 e^t+1}-\dfrac{c_1^2 e^{2 t}}{\left(c_1 e^t+1\right)^2} = \dfrac{c_1 e^t}{\left(c_1 e^t+1\right)^2}$$

**Step 2:**

$$\dfrac{dP}{dt} = P(1-P) = \dfrac{c_1 e^t}{1 + c_1 e^t}\left(1 - \dfrac{c_1 e^t}{1 + c_1 e^t}\right) = \dfrac{c_1 e^t}{c_1 e^t+1}-\dfrac{c_1^2 e^{2 t}}{\left(c_1 e^t+1\right)^2}  = \dfrac{c_1 e^t}{\left(c_1 e^t+1\right)^2}$$